# How to create API that will force download file with HAPI JS

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm working with NodeJS and using HAPI to create API for upload and download file. When uploading, I read the file information (filename, mime type and file content) and store it in database. File content is stored as base64 encoded string.

What I want to do is to create API, so when client hits it will be forced to download a file that is constructed based on the stored information using the code below

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path:'/file', 
  handler: function (request, reply) {

    var fileData = // get file content; 
    var mime = // get file mime-type;

    var fileBuffer = new Buffer(fileData, 'base64');
    reply(fileBuffer)
      .header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName)
      .header('Content-type', mime).header('Content-length', fileBuffer.length).encoding('binary');
  }
})
```

But this code looks like still not work, if I hit the API it will be loading process forever and no file downloaded. Anybody can give me suggestion on how to do it correctly?

#### UPDATE

the code is correct and works perfectly. the problem I had before is caused by another reason, incorrect encoding/decoding mechanism.

Comment: What is the problem with the code at this point?

Comment: sorry I posted incomplete question before. I have updated it. thanks @morgh

Answer (score 0):

Check out the inert plugin for hapi which handles files, the repo is [here](https://github.com/hapijs/inert)

Comment: Yes, inert do propose a solution. So +1. But you'd better write a more satisfying answer